# Ruby on Rails rendering via an ajax call doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rendering

I have an issue with loading some content into a content div via an ajax call.

I have ChangeAvatarController in my application with the following code.

```
class ChangeAvatarController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
       render '_index', :layout => false
    end
  end
end
```

And in my dashboard.html.erb I have the following div

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

I have the following piece of code

app/view/change_avatar/_index.html.erb:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });
</script>
```

And app/view/change_avatar/_index.js.erb

```
$("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index')%>");
```

I have the following route in my rooutes.rb

```
get 'change_avatar/index'
```

So,

When I render the index.html.erb with the following way It's perfect:

```
<div id="content>
    <%= render 'change_avatar/index', remote: true %>
</div>
```

First Name: John

Last Name: Doe

Full Name: John Doe

However, when I use the following way,

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
       url: "/change_avatar/index",
       type: 'GET',
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){
           $("#content").append(html);
       }
    })
</script>

<div id='content'>


</div>
```

I get this one:

First Name:

Last Name:

Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

There is no error in javascript debug console.

I can't figure out what the problem is,

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
       url: "/change_avatar/index",
       type: 'GET',
       cache: false
    })
</script>
```

Would suffice since I'm assuming you have a changeavatars/index.js.erb file with:

```
  $("#content").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'changeavatars/index') %>")
```

Also, you should change `render '_index'` in your controller to just `render :index`

Comment: Yeap I have index.js.erb file in my changeavatars folder. When I chnage render '_index' to render 'index' in my controller, I'm getting the following error.

Comment: jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:350 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:350
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:351)
    at text script (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10373)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:9333)
    at done (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:9790)
    at callback (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10312)
    at Object.send (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10322)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:9739)